# MySQL: delete from the result of a previous query using the same table

Tags: mysql

I get an error while trying to execute this query since MySQL realize that I'm trying to delete some records by a set of results which comes from a JOIN on the same table.

How can I rewrite the query?

```
DELETE FROM hr_descr2 
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT 
        a.id
    FROM
        hr_descr2 a,
        hyperreview_descr b    
    WHERE
        a.titolo = b.titolo
        AND a.recensione != b.recensione
        AND a.recensione != ''
        AND b.recensione != ''
        AND ABS(LENGTH(a.recensione) - LENGTH(b.recensione)) > 40);
```

I've also tried to rewrite the query in this way but it doesn't work:

```
WITH temp AS(SELECT 
        a.id
    FROM
        hr_descr2 a,
        hyperreview_descr b    
    WHERE
        a.titolo = b.titolo
        AND a.recensione != b.recensione
        AND a.recensione != ''
        AND b.recensione != ''
        AND ABS(LENGTH(a.recensione) - LENGTH(b.recensione)) > 40)
DELETE FROM hr_descr2 
WHERE
    id IN (select id from temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead you can use

```
DELETE a FROM
    hr_descr2 a,
    hyperreview_descr b    
WHERE
    a.titolo = b.titolo
    AND a.recensione != b.recensione
    AND a.recensione != ''
    AND b.recensione != ''
    AND ABS(LENGTH(a.recensione) - LENGTH(b.recensione)) > 40
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think MySQL Supports CTEs, so the with is not syntactically correct.

I haven't tried this but I think something like this should work?

```
DELETE hr_descr2 
FROM hr_descr2 a,
    hyperreview_descr b    
WHERE
    a.titolo = b.titolo
    AND a.recensione != b.recensione
    AND a.recensione != ''
    AND b.recensione != ''
    AND ABS(LENGTH(a.recensione) - LENGTH(b.recensione)) > 40);
```

Comment: Yes, it supports them.. and CTE is a name specific to microsoft, also Oracle supports them but they call them in another name.

Comment: @Revious what version of mysql are you running?

Comment: 5 if I'm not wrong.. but the CTE work only with the selects in mysql I think

Comment: @Revious, I'm pretty sure MySQL does not support CTEs using `WITH` (or at all, unless you consider sub-selects).  At least not in 5.5.35.  Also, not an expert, but I think CTE is a common name used, not specific to MS or SQL Server.

Comment: shame on me.. sorry, I was really sure. +1 and my apologizes